# Cannot identify strange space between links in horizontal menu

Tags: html, css

I'm creating simple horizontal menu. When I hover item it changes background color, but lefts some strange 3px space on left side of the link, and I cannot identify why it shows up, and how to remove it.

Menu is here: http://pokerzysta.site44.com/ (`Linki, Posty, Forum, Dodaj`)
Any idea what's wrong with it?

Comment: Use this **HTML** code <ul id="main-menu" class="horizontal-list fleft"> <li><a href="#">Linki</a></li><li><a href="#">Posty</a></li><li><a href="#">Forum</a></li><li><a href="#">Dodaj</a></li><li></li> </ul> Working DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/enve/Dkfys/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats because you're displaying the list in a horizontal manner with `display: inline-block;`.
What is rendered there are white spaces from your HTML markup (most likely line-breaks after the li-tags).

If you put the li-tags in your html without white-space and line-breaks this won't happen:

```
<ul id="main-menu" class="horizontal-list fleft">
    <li><a href="#">Linki</a></li><li><a href="#">Posty</a></li><li><a href="#">Forum</a></li><li><a href="#">Dodaj</a><li>
</ul>
```

@cimmanon pointed to a great article by Chris Coyier about displaying list navigations horizontally: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: See also:  http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: Also the comments on this article are really good and give more information about this topic. I edit your link into my answer so it's noted more easier.

Answer (score 1):

There're whitespaces between your LI-Elements. By removing them or using

```
float: left;
```

will solute also the problem (but after your UL you should use a clear: both)

Answer (score 1):

your links are inline block, so the HTML whitespace actually uses space ;) A simple trick would be to set the font-size to 0 on the ul and reset the right font size in the li's

in your case:

```
.horizontal-list {
   font-size: 0;
}

.horizontal-list li{
   font-size: 17px;
}
```